# How to get cookies from request module in node.js?

Tags: node.js, cookies, node-request

```
function getCookies(){

    request('http://google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(response.headers);
        }
    })
}
```

**Result**

```
{ date: 'Fri, 11 Dec 2015 07:15:50 GMT',
  expires: '-1',
  'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=EUC-KR',
  p3p: 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."',
  server: 'gws',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'set-cookie': 
   [ 'PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:TM=1449818150:LM=1449818150:V=1:S=Q3BB20FA6TkaZymd; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-2015 16:02:17 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.kr',
     'NID=74=hnriWxk7N9jHtP5W0qgaxrwD1YuNKOmJg748ucxWilu9jaqHJVovfkYdvMr0tlp-VToID5cdTNDSXNXqr4M8umJ9traab67x2xZKfu3hJbsBRXeVvyiCOcwZ8bkXNcU4; expires=Sat, 11-Jun-2016 07:15:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.kr; HttpOnly' ],
  'accept-ranges': 'none',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  connection: 'close' }
```

I want to pick up value of '**set-cookie**' from response headers. How to pick it up? Is there any cool and simple way? Should I use for statement from filedkey, or. What should I do? I don't know I'm totally newbie on Javascript. Thanks...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
function getCookies(callback){

    request('http://google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return callback(null, response.headers['set-cookie']);
        } else {
            return callback(error);
        }
    })
}
```

then you can call:

```
getCookies(function(err, res){
    if(!err)
       console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: wow, really? this is a much less friendly way to get cookies compared to express on the server side where i can just say "req.cookies.cookieName"

Answer (score 12):

Here is how you can use request-cookies as @brandonscript said.

```
var request = require('request');
var Cookie = require('request-cookies').Cookie;

request.get('https://google.com', function(err, response, body) {
  var rawcookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];
  for (var i in rawcookies) {
    var cookie = new Cookie(rawcookies[i]);
    console.log(cookie.key, cookie.value, cookie.expires);
  }
});
```

Sample output from google:

```
NID 98=FfYHDY9-40JzE78qxIpaMugODJ4y4zJIydluKUffvh1lDs70DYk7vrlmw2ca2gD54ywx5WV44Utz9EdLOdFE6IcW2BUGfiVpHZx3kWh69tT_eWlXZTiFkRo7TVr_9WWH 2017-09-08T04:22:41.000Z
```

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking with Node, if it's a common problem to solve, someone's already gone to the trouble to write and publish something on npm.

For example, [request-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-cookies)!

In particular, I think you'll find the `toJSON()` method most helpful, though admittedly the package's documentation is rather light. You can check out the [tests](https://github.com/lalitkapoor/request-cookies/tree/master/test) for some working examples.

That said, request already has some extensive documentation on cookies as well - you might find this suits your needs:

> Cookies are disabled by default (else, they would be used in subsequent requests). To enable cookies, set `jar` to `true` (either in `defaults` or `options`).

(Scroll down to the bottom of the [readme](https://github.com/request/request) to find the bits about cookies).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care what's in the `cookie` and you just want to use it, try this clean approach:

```
var request = require('request');
var j = request.jar();
var request = request.defaults({jar:j});
request('http://www.google.com', function () {
  request('http://images.google.com', function (error, response, body){
     // this request will will have the cookie which first request received
     // do stuff
  });
});
```

Comment: This is very simple and neat solution!

Answer (score 1):

When you import request module, probably you did it like this

```
var request = require('request');
```

Add one line as follows

```
var request = require('request');
var request = request.defaults({jar: true})
```

And just use request module as usual. You can get the set cookie response.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

npm install tough-cookie

```
const request = require("request");
const tough = require('tough-cookie');
const  Cookie = tough.Cookie;

request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
        const cookie = Cookie.parse(response.headers['set-cookie'][0]);
        console.log(cookie.cookieString());
});
```